# Codeigniter select where AND

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, flutter

How to do select where and with code igniter ?
`//select * from item_user where email="myemail@gmail.com" and passwd="123"`

```
function index_get() {
    $email = $this->get('email');
    $passwd = $this->get('passwd');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM web_user ";

    if ($email != '') {
        $this->db->where('email', $email & 'passwd', $passwd);
        $item_user = $this->db->get('web_user')->result();

    }

    if ($item_user) {
        $this->response([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'found',
            'data' => $item_user
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
    } else {
        $this->response([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => 'not found',
        ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

i think my wrong syntax is around `$this->db->where('email', $email & 'passwd', $passwd);`
please help me, and where to learn this kind of CI stuff easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hope this helps

```
 $this->db->where('email', $email);
 $this->db->where('passwd', $passwd);
 $item_user = $this->db->get('web_user')->result();
```

> If you are using **GET** Method Get the data using this

```
$email =  $this->input->get('email');
```

> If you are using **POST** Method Get the data using this

```
$email = $this->input->post('email');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try replacing this

```
$this->db->where('email', $email & 'passwd', $passwd);
```

with

```
$this->db->where(array('email' => $email, 'passwd' => $passwd));
```

// Produces: WHERE email = 'your_email_val_here' AND passwd = 'your_password_val_here'

and you can learn more like these stuff in [codeigniter official documention](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html) of query building